# Adding to a Google Doc from a Google Spreadsheet Using Apps Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I'm new to using the DocumentApp in Google Apps, so looking for some help!

I'm trying to create an FAQ (in a Google Doc) automatically from a spreadsheet.  If certain conditions are met in the spreadsheet row, I want the script to find the category of the question in the document and insert a new question and response underneath it (pushing anything already there back).

So I'd have a document that looks like this:

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1fjb3RO6hUY6n7x0bu6WvtcleMWRNC8VQ9U82hXiGqcY/edit?usp=sharing

And a spreadsheet that looks like this:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1fb3ceqP6142_C7QQ1PfkWtVNswOyzOxkWCofvauf4Ps/edit?usp=sharing

And this is the code I'm trying to use.  I'm getting a ton of errors- mainly because I don't have a good grasp on what the different elements involved are.  Can anyone point me in the right direction?

```
function insertnewquestion() {

//(works fine)Get active document and related spreadsheet  
var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("xxxxxxx");
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("xxxxx");

//(works fine)Go through the various rows in the spreadsheet up to the last row  
for (var row = 2; row <= sheet.getLastRow(); ++row) {
var status = sheet.getRange(row,4).getValue();
var question = sheet.getRange(row,1).getValue();
var response = sheet.getRange(row,2).getValue();
var category = sheet.getRange(row,3).getValue();
var date = sheet.getRange(row,5).getValue();

//(works fine)find rows with blank status and a response filled in    
if (status !== "Entered" && response !== "") {

//(errors! this is where i need help) find the pertinent header  

var categoryposition = body.findText(category);  //looking for the category header- new text should be added after this, the idea is that what was already under this header will move down
var questionheader = categoryposition.appendText(question);  //trying here to add in question text after where the category was found
questionheader.setHeading(DocumentApp.ParagraphHeading.HEADING3); //set question text as heading 3 (so it shows up on table of contents)
questionheader.appendText("\r"+"\r"+response+"\r\r"); //add line breaks and then the response text in normal font, then more line breaks to put space between new stuff and old stuff

//(works fine)Mark in the spreadsheet that it was entered in FAQ and the date so that it isn't double entered next time the script runs

sheet.getRange(row,4).setValue("Entered");
var currentTime = new Date()
var month = currentTime.getMonth() + 1
var day = currentTime.getDate()
var year = currentTime.getFullYear()
var date = (month + "/" + day + "/" + year) 

sheet.getRange(row,5).setValue(date);

}
  else {continue}


}

//(need help!) Refresh table of contents to include new questions

//no idea how to do this!

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the code you are referring to `body.findText(category);` where it should be `doc.findText(category);`. Also for the line:

```
var categoryposition = body.findText(category);
```

it returns the `RangeElement — a search result indicating the position of the search text, or null if there is no match`

Before adding any lines of code you have to check for null value in categoryposition.

The text class has a method to insert text in particular offset value to particular String value gives as shown [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/text#insertText(Integer,String)).

Hope that is helpful.